# jQuery and Wordpress links not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

Got a problem with my WordPress menu. After I insert the jquery my links (in the menu and in sidebars won't work. What to do? Thank you!

My code:

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
   <a href="#">Link text</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a>Text</a></li>
       <li><a>Text</a></li>
       <li><a>Text</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('li.menu-item').each(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);
    $($dropdown).click(".menu-item a", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $ul = $("ul.sub-menu", $dropdown);
      $('ul.sub-menu').toggle();
      $("ul.sub-menu").not($ul).hide();
      return false;
    });

});

  $('html').click(function(){
    $("ul.sub-menu").hide();
  });

});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you adding to the page?

Comment: are you adding the script tag that grabs 1.10.2 your self, or was it already there?

Comment: Put it there myself. <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a problem with the event propagation. If a link within a sub-menu is clicked the click event propagates to the surrounding menu-item and triggers your JS code.

Please try to add this code to prevent the propagation effect:

```
$( "ul.sub-menu a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Oops, it worked for the main navigation, but not for the sidebars.

Comment: would you please provide a html snippet from the links in the sidebar that are not working? or can you provide the url to the website (if it is public)?

Comment: Haha, sorry for the spam. I figured it out, just took your script once more for the sidebar widgets. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

please fix the issue by replacing below script

```
<li class="menu-item> to <li class="menu-item">
```

Comment: Thank you, but that was just a careless mistake from me when I copied the script...